# Unity Facebook SDK issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to solve these facebook SDK issues on Unity latest version 
Many other people tried on their Unity and it was working fine but on my machine and my friends machine with latest version doesnt work well even though others tried on latest Unity version

[facebook sdk errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMB4M.png)

The game does not run and asks to fix issues before building or running

Comment: Can you mention exact issue you are facing while building the app or paste the error message

Comment: yes I've included this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMB4M.png